# Dimensions of sparse matrix after multiplication

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

I am currently trying to do matrix multiplication with sparse matrices through the scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.multiply function.

From my understanding of matrix multiplication, if I multiply a matrix **beta*MS** of shape (10000, 10000) with a matrix **rt** of shape (10000, 1), I should be getting a resultant matrix **rhat** of shape (10000, 1). However, when I was implementing my code which I will include below, I ended up getting a matrix of shape (10000, 10000).

May I ask why is this so?

Please refer to the image attached for the code and output. [output of code showing the shape of each matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dhelv.png)

Thank you in advance for the assistance. I'm new to this so let me know if there is anything wrong with the post.

Comment: Multiply is element-wise. Use .dot() or the matmul operator @

Comment: Is there anyway to do matrix multiplication directly on two sparse matrices? I understand that the matmul and .dot() function belongs to numpy so I'll have to convert the sparse matrices to numpy objects before I can apply them right?

Comment: Both (beta * ms).dot(rt) or (beta * ms) @ rt should work. The second is preferred IMO.